# Using ThreadLocal vs. a HashMap with Thread as a key

Tags: java, servlets, concurrency, thread-safety

I would like to reuse instances of non-thread safe classes for performance reasons in a Servlet. I have two options,

1. use ThreadLocal where in Java takes care of doing the instance management per thread
2. use a static HashMap which uses Thread as the HashMap key and the instances are managed at this level

With the ThreadLocal approach there are potentials for memory leaks esp in Servlet enviornment. Because of this, I am thinking of using the 2nd option, I was wondering if anyone has experience in using this approach and any pitfalls of using the same?

Comment: `ThreadLocal` _is_ a `HashMap` with the thread as the key.

Comment: There are probably more potentials for memory leaks with your static `HashMap`.

Comment: @JimGarrison the ThreadLocal implementation is **vastly** more sophisticated than that.

Comment: @JimGarrison I just looked inside the OpenJDK implementation and it uses a ThreadLocalMap (a.k.a. HashMap) which is a member of the Thread class. So yes, there is a map involved but it is also a "thread local" variable with the key being a hash to access which variable you're interested in, not which thread the variable belongs to. This means no synchronization is involved for accessing a ThreadLocal variable. Well, that's not entirely true. There is synchronization involved for adding new ThreadLocal variables via incrementing an atomic int counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefer the ThreadLocal approach because it is likely synchronized (or better yet, requires no synchronization) at the correct granularity and no larger.

If you roll your own solution using HashMap you'll have to acquire a lock over the HashMap every time you want to access any thread-local data. Why? Because a new thread could be created and threads can die. These are implicitly adding/removing items from a HashMap, which require synchronization on the full HashMap. You'll also have quite the time keeping object lifetimes straight because HashMap will keep alive all items it contains as long as it is referable from any thread. That is not how ThreadLocal store behaves.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not `ThreadLocal` itself, but the way it's being used. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17975255/660143) for a detailed explanation. So, your own implementation won't make a difference.