# where to code ThreadLocal.remove() in aspectj class

Tags: java, aspectj, thread-local, aop, thread-local-storage

/* 
We are using Aspect to do AOP on some existing application and we also used threadlocal to store GUId. we are using @Around annotation.
At the start of the transaction we are setting the GUID in transaction with initialValue() method.

Issue is as we know when we are using threadlocal we should also take care about removing the data from threadlocal otherwise it may result i outofmemory execption. if i am removing it at 
the last of the aspect it is corrupting the code and changing the UUID value.

Please suggest how we can achieve it without outofmemory.

Code :- 
*/

```
@Aspect
public class DemoAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* *.*(..)) ")
    public void logging() {}

    private static ThreadLocal<String> id = new ThreadLocal<String>() {
        @Override
        protected String initialValue(){
            return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        } 
    };

    @Around("logging()")
    public Object tracing(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        String methodSignature=thisJoinPoint.getSignature().toString();
        if(id.get().toString()==null || id.get().toString().length()==0)
        id.set(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        System.out.println("Entering into "+methodSignature);
        Object ret = thisJoinPoint.proceed();
        System.out.println(id.get().toString());
        System.out.println("Exiting into "+methodSignature);
        //id.remove();
        return ret;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before we start a little hint: If you write `@Around("logging()")` your pointcut method should be renamed from `loggingResponseTime()` to actually `logging()`, otherwise the aspect will not work.

Now as for your real problem: You are making a typical beginners' mistake by advising code too broadly, i.e. you are intercepting *all* method executions (outside the JDK). If you use Eclipse and AJDT and you put your cursor into the `tracing()` advice you will see something like this in the AspectJ "cross reference" window using your current pointcut:

[image: AspectJ cross reference view for <code>tracing()</code> advice]

You can immediately see your problem: Your pointcut captures code in your anonymous `ThreadLocal` subclass. This leads to endless recursion and finally to the `StackOverflowError` as you can see in your own callstack if you inspect it.

Now here is some sample code demonstrating the problem for other people's reference:

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(bar(foo()));
    }

    public static String bar(String text) {
        return text + "bar";
    }

    private static String foo() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.util.UUID;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class DemoAspect {
    private static ThreadLocal<String> id = new ThreadLocal<String>() {
        @Override
        protected String initialValue() {
            return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        }
    };

    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
    public void logging() {}

    @Around("logging()")
    public Object tracing(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        String methodSignature = thisJoinPoint.getSignature().toString();
        if (id.get().toString() == null || id.get().toString().length() == 0)
            id.set(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        System.out.println("Entering into " + methodSignature);
        Object ret = thisJoinPoint.proceed();
        System.out.println(id.get().toString());
        System.out.println("Exiting from " + methodSignature);
        id.remove();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

**Console output:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.SignatureImpl$CacheImpl.get(SignatureImpl.java:217)
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.SignatureImpl.toString(SignatureImpl.java:50)
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.SignatureImpl.toString(SignatureImpl.java:62)
    at de.scrum_master.aspect.DemoAspect$1.initialValue_aroundBody1$advice(DemoAspect.aj:29)
    at de.scrum_master.aspect.DemoAspect$1.initialValue(DemoAspect.aj:1)
    at de.scrum_master.aspect.DemoAspect$1.initialValue(DemoAspect.aj:1)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:160)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:150)
    at de.scrum_master.aspect.DemoAspect$1.initialValue_aroundBody1$advice(DemoAspect.aj:30)
    at de.scrum_master.aspect.DemoAspect$1.initialValue(DemoAspect.aj:1)
    at de.scrum_master.aspect.DemoAspect$1.initialValue(DemoAspect.aj:1)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:160)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:150)
    (...)
```

So what can you do? It is actually quite simple: Just exclude the joinpoints you do not really want to intercept from your pointcut. For that you have several options. I am just naming a few:

**A)** Put your aspects into a specific package and exclude all (aspect) classes in that package:

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && !within(de.scrum_master.aspect..*)")
```

**B)** Exclude all classes annotated by `@Aspect`:

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && !within(@org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect *)")
```

**C)** Exclude all (aspect) classes matching a certain naming scheme like `*Aspect`:

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && !within(*..*Aspect)")
```

**D)** Exclude code from all `ThreadLocal` subclasses (`+` syntax):

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && !within(ThreadLocal+)")
```

In each case the result will be the same:

```
Entering into void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[])
Entering into String de.scrum_master.app.Application.foo()
d2b83f5f-7282-4c06-9b81-6601c8e0499d
Exiting from String de.scrum_master.app.Application.foo()
Entering into String de.scrum_master.app.Application.bar(String)
0d1c9463-4bbd-427d-9d64-c7f3967756cf
Exiting from String de.scrum_master.app.Application.bar(String)
foobar
aa96bbbd-a1a1-450f-ae6e-77ab204c5fb2
Exiting from void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[])
```

By the way: I have strong doubts about your usage of `UUID`s because I see no value in creating expensive objects here. How about just logging timestamps? Why do you need globally unique IDs for logging? They tell you nothing. Furthermore, not only are you creating one ID per thread, but if you use the uncommented `id.remove()` you even create one per call! Sorry, but this is bloat, it slows down your code and creates lots of unnecessary objects. I do not think this is wise.

---

**Update:**

I forgot to explain the reason for the endless recursion: Your advice calls `ThreadLocal.get()`, assuming it could be null. Actually it cannot be because if the value has not been initialised, `get()` does so by utilising `initialValue()`. Even if you manually call `remove()`, the next time you call `get()` it will again initialise the value again and so forth. This is [documented behaviour](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html#get()):

> Returns the value in the current thread's copy of this thread-local variable. If the variable has no value for the current thread, it is first initialized to the value returned by an invocation of the `initialValue()` method.

So what happens, step by step?

- A method is called.
- Your around advice kicks in.
- You call `id.get()` from the advice.
- `ThreadLocal.get()` checks if a value is set, notices that there is none and calls your overridden `initialValue()` method.
- Because the overridden `initialValue()` method is captured by your match-all pointcut `execution(* *(..))`, again your advice kicks in *before* the initial value has been set. The end result is that the loop starts again and so forth - endless recursion, quod erat demonstrandum.

So actually your problem boils down to calling `get()` on an uninitialised `ThreadLocal` subclass from an advice while simultaneously targetting its user-defined `initialValue()` method with the same advice. This is what creates the endless recursion and ultimately makes your stack overflow.

My recommendation is to exclude your aspect from the pointcut, see example pointcuts above. You should also get rid of the `null` check for the `ThreadLocal` value because it is superfluous. Last but not least, I assume you want one `ThreadLocal` value per thread and not one per method call. So you can do without any `set()` or `remove()` calls altogether.

**Modified driver class, creating an additional thread:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(bar(foo()));
            }
        }).start();
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }

    public static String bar(String text) {
        return text + "bar";
    }

    private static String foo() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

**Improved aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.util.UUID;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.Signature;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class DemoAspect {
    private static ThreadLocal<UUID> id = new ThreadLocal<UUID>() {
        @Override
        protected UUID initialValue() {
            return UUID.randomUUID();
        }
    };

    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && !within(DemoAspect)")
    public void logging() {}

    @Around("logging()")
    public Object tracing(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Signature methodSignature = thisJoinPoint.getSignature();
        System.out.println(
            "Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() +
            "[" + id.get() +
            "] >>> " + methodSignature
        );
        Object result = thisJoinPoint.proceed();
        System.out.println(
            "Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() +
            "[" + id.get() +
            "] <<< " + methodSignature
        );
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Console output:**

```
Thread 1[549d0856-0a92-4031-9331-a1317d6a43c4] >>> void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[])
Thread 9[32c8444c-0f1f-4023-9b97-69d5beda3b4c] >>> void de.scrum_master.app.Application.1.run()
Thread 9[32c8444c-0f1f-4023-9b97-69d5beda3b4c] >>> String de.scrum_master.app.Application.access$0()
Thread 9[32c8444c-0f1f-4023-9b97-69d5beda3b4c] >>> String de.scrum_master.app.Application.foo()
Thread 9[32c8444c-0f1f-4023-9b97-69d5beda3b4c] <<< String de.scrum_master.app.Application.foo()
Thread 9[32c8444c-0f1f-4023-9b97-69d5beda3b4c] <<< String de.scrum_master.app.Application.access$0()
Thread 9[32c8444c-0f1f-4023-9b97-69d5beda3b4c] >>> String de.scrum_master.app.Application.bar(String)
Thread 9[32c8444c-0f1f-4023-9b97-69d5beda3b4c] <<< String de.scrum_master.app.Application.bar(String)
foobar
Thread 9[32c8444c-0f1f-4023-9b97-69d5beda3b4c] <<< void de.scrum_master.app.Application.1.run()
Thread 1[549d0856-0a92-4031-9331-a1317d6a43c4] <<< void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[])
```

As you can see, threads already have unique IDs, so maybe you want consider implementing your aspect without any UUIDs altogether.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kriegaex. I did some mistakes while modifying the code before putting it on stackoverflow. Regarding the usage of UUID, i wanted to capture the response time of all methods for 1 transaction. here my transactions are going through multiple JVMs. hence i need to create 1 UUID at first JVM(App) then i need to forward the same to other JVM. Actual issue is to remove the uuid from threadlocal once thread completes. In your example we will get two threadlocal objects which will remain in memory and will not be garbage collected & may result in outofmemory exception in load situation.

Comment: I am not sure but there should be some way to handle memory while using threadlocal with aspects./

Comment: `ThreadLocal` memory handling is not the problem here, but you producing an endless loop by false usage!!! Look at the stacktrace. BTW, I would appreciate you accepting and upvoting my correct and very detailed answer.

Comment: i dont have 15 reputatiosn to upvote any answer. i was worried about memoery leaks beacuse of classloader leaks in App Servers. check out this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968803/threadlocal-memory-leak

Comment: As I said, that problem is totally unrelated to yours here. Please do not mix unrelated stuff, concentrate on the problem at hand and find the root cause, which I have done for you. Now you can do `ThreadLocal` memory handling as much as you like if you think you have another problem there. But please do not discuss it here. Keep focused.