# SpringBoot: how to pass argument (request id) from controller through all program?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, slf4j

I use SpringBoot app. Every request has ID. And I has to use this ID when log errors in some services and more lowlevel places of the program. How can I  implement it? Thank you!

Comment: you can use `@RequestParam` or `@Pathvariable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ThreadLocal to store that ID for a specific Thread.

Then, in your services you can get that ID throghtout the method `ThreadLocal#get`.

**For example (This is just an approach):**

```
class AppProvider {
    public static final ThreadLocal<String> APP_CONTEXT = new ThreadLocal<String>();
}

class Controller {
    public void users(@RequestParam String id) {
        AppProvider.APP_CONTEXT.set(id);
        .......
    }
}

class Service {
    try {
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(String.format("Id: %s", AppProvider.APP_CONTEXT.get()));
    }
}
```

This is just an approach using ThreadLocal.

**Look a this for Memory leak handling:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/17975255/1715121

Answer (score 0):

For adding a context id to you log you can use the MDC :

in your code :

```
 MDC.put("first", "Dorothy");
```

in your logback.xml

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender"> 
  <layout>
    <Pattern>%X{first} %X{last} - %m%n</Pattern>
  </layout> 
</appender>
```

See https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html